# Select columns and group by columns in function arguments

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function so that I can input any columns to be described both at the overall level and by a grouping variable.

However, I am having trouble with getting output for grouped results.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(gender=c("m", "f", "m","m"), age=c("18-22","23-32","23-32","50-60"), income=c("low", "low", "medium", "high"), group=c("A", "A", "B", "B"))
> df
  gender   age income group
1      m 18-22    low     A
2      f 23-32    low     A
3      m 23-32 medium     B
4      m 50-60   high     B
```

Function:

```
library(dplyr)
make_sum <- function(data=df, cols, group_var) {
data %>% dplyr::select(cols)  %>%
  # print tables with frequency and proportions
  apply(2, function(x) {
    n <-  table(x, useNA = "no")
    prop=round(n/length(x[!is.na(x)])*100,2)
    print(cbind(n, prop)) 
  })
  # print tables by group
data %>% dplyr::select(cols, vars(group_var))  %>%
  apply(2, function(x) {
    n <-  table(x, vars(group_var),useNA = "no")
   print(n)
  })  
}

cols <- df %>% dplyr::select(gender,age, income) %>% names()

make_sum(data=df, cols=cols, group_var="group")
```

I get the proper output for the overall tables but not the grouped, with this error showing:

```
Error: `vars(group_var)` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list
```

Desired output (example) for grouped gender variable:

```
    A B
  f 1 0
  m 1 2
```

Comment: The `vars` wrapper work within tidyverse functions, you are calling it on `base R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `apply` with `MARGIN = 2`, `summarise_all` can be called here.  Also, the `vars` wrapped is applied along with a tidyverse function.  Here, inorder to get the  frequency, an option is to subset the column with `[[` which is more direct.  Also, as `summarise` returns only a single row (for each group - if there is grouping variable), we can wrap the output in a `list`

```
make_sum <- function(data=df, cols, group_var) {
data %>% 
  dplyr::select(cols)  %>%
   summarise_all(~ {

    n <-  table(.,  data[[group_var]], useNA = "no")
    #list(round(n/length(.[!is.na(.)])*100,2))
    list(n)

  })
  }


cols <- df %>%
            dplyr::select(gender,age, income) %>%
            names()

out <- make_sum(data=df, cols=cols, group_var="group")
out$gender
#[[1]]

#.   A B
#  f 1 0
#  m 1 2
```

Comment: This worked great. I modified the function as follows to print proportions (by column) in the same table:                                                                                         
 make_sum <- function(data=df, cols, group_var) {
  data %>% 
    dplyr::select(cols)  %>%
     summarise_all(~ {
      n <-  table(.,  data[[group_var]], useNA = "no")
      p <-  round(prop.table(n, 2)*100,2)
      print(list(cbind(n,p))) 
    })
    }